# A full binary tree has every edge colored black or white randomly. What is the probability of having a white path from the root to some leaf?

Tags: probability

> A full binary tree has every edge colored black or white randomly.
> What is the probability of having a white path from the root to some
> leaf?
>
> A) $\Theta(1)$
>
> B) $\Theta(\frac{1}{n})$
>
> C)  $e^{-\Theta(n)}$
>
> D) $(\log n)^{-\Theta(1)}$

Every edge has a 0.5 chance of being white and 0.5 chance of being black. The tree is of depth $n$ so therefore it has $2^n$ leafs with distinct paths to them and every path is of length $n$.

I'm not sure how to solve this question. I'm really not sure where to start. The odds of a random path being white is $(\frac{1}{2})^n$ and there are $2^n$ different paths to the leafs, but it's not true that $P=2^n(\frac{1}{2})^n $ Because that just equals 1.

Comment: How many edges do you have between the root and a leaf? More to the point, how many paths can you have from the root to a given leaf? Finally, ask yourself whether the event of there being a path from the root to leaf $a$ is disjoint to the one of there being a path to some other leaf $b$

Comment: As I said, you have $2^n$ paths to $2^n$ leafs. I understand there's some kind of dependency but I'm still not sure how to solve this

Answer (score 3):

Hint: start from the top and work down. Right from the start, you have a 25% chance of failing (both edges from the root are black).  Apply this r
recursively.

---

To expand a bit on this, separate into four different cases depending on our two child edges, BB (black/black), BW, WB and WW, each having probability $\frac{1}{4}$:

\begin{align}
p(n) &= \frac{1}{4}\cdot 0 \quad &\text{(BB)}\\
     &+\frac{1}{4}\cdot p(n-1) &\text{(BW)}\\
     &+\frac{1}{4}\cdot p(n-1) &\text{(WB)}\\
     &+\frac{1}{4}\cdot (1 - (1 - p(n-1))^2) &\text{(BB)}\\
\end{align}

Note that for the last case we use $1$ minus the chance that both *fail*, which gives the chance that at least one succeeds. Simplifying this we get:

$$p(n) = p(n-1) - \frac{1}{4}p(n-1)^2$$
$$p(n) = p(n-1)(1 - \frac{1}{4}p(n-1))$$

Also keep in mind that $p(1) = 1$, because the path from a node to itself always exists.

Solving these types of recurrences isn't easy, see Did's answer to go from here (or better, attempt it yourself).

Comment: I tried but as soon as I reach to the 3rd level I have no idea what to do. OK, so in the start I have 0.75 chance of having a white path. Now let's go down another level. It's not that I have 4 different 0.5 chance tests that will give me a white path, it's only if the path up until the parent vertex is white that it will give me that path. So I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @panthersfan92 You have to be more precise and general. Try to write down the function $p(n)$ giving the probability of a tree with depth $n$ in terms of a sum of $p(n-1)$ and then solve the recurrence.

Comment: I think of breaking it into 3 cases: both level 1 edges are black, 1 level 1 edge is black, and no level 1 edges are black. Note that these cases respectively create 0, 1 and 2 independent trees of depth $n-1$

Comment: @orlp -> I honestly tried and I have no idea how to write a formula for the genral case. I barely know how to write it to the next level in any way that's useful.

Comment: @orlp I don't think your is correct. Clearly p(2) should be $.75$, not $.25$.

Comment: @Joe Oops, I made a dumb simplifying error. I removed the parts that were wrong.

Comment: "Can you take it from here?" In case you would mean by this query that the OP finds an explicit formula for $p(n)$ in terms of $n$, please be aware that *quadratic* recursions such as the present one are notoriously impossible to solve in general. So, either you have a specific trick in mind, that would allow to solve this specific case, or you are sending the OP into a wall. Please explain.

Comment: @Did I didn't mean to imply that it was easy from here, but finding the recurrence is step 1 that OP seemed to be stuck on.

Comment: Sorry but "Can you take it from here?", and a few equivalent formulations, are used to signal that, after the steps explained in an answer, the rest of a proof is direct. Weren't you yourself convinced this was so in the present case, when you posted your answer?

Comment: @Did Before correcting my mistake, yes, after no. I will change the wording if that is how other people interpret it, I thought it was used as a general ending to an answer that is a hint or partial answer, not to imply (lack of) difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

The recursion

> $$p(n)=p(n-1)-\frac14p(n)^2$$

is a simple consequence of the one-level decomposition of the tree. To deduce some asymptotics of $p(n)$, one first notes that every $p(n)$ is in $(0,1]$ hence $p(n)$ is a nondecreasing function of $p(n-1)$.

Now, one is ready to show that, for every $n\geqslant0$,

> $$\frac3{n+3}\leqslant p(n)\leqslant\frac4{n+4}\tag{$\ast$}$$

The $n=0$ case of $(\ast)$ follows from the value $p(0)=1$. (If one is uncomfortable with the (perfectly legit) notion that $p(0)$ exists and that $p(0)=1$, one can instead check $(\ast)$ for $p(1)=\frac34$).

If $(\ast)$ holds for some $n\geqslant0$, $$\frac3{n+3}-\frac14\left(\frac3{n+3}\right)^2\leqslant p(n+1)\leqslant\frac4{n+4}-\frac14\left(\frac4{n+4}\right)^2$$
hence, to deduce that $(\ast)$ holds for $n+1$ as well, it suffices to check that, for every $n\geqslant0$, $$\frac3{n+4}\leqslant\frac3{n+3}-\frac14\left(\frac3{n+3}\right)^2\tag{1}$$ and that, for every $n\geqslant0$, $$\frac4{n+4}-\frac14\left(\frac4{n+4}\right)^2\leqslant\frac4{n+5}\tag{2}$$
It happens that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are both direct hence all this proves that $(\ast)$ holds for every $n\geqslant0$. In particular,

> $$p(n)=\Theta\left(\frac1n\right)$$

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on your _ansatz_ of $\frac  3 {n + 3}$ or I else I'm afraid that the answer will have little educational value to OP other than that the stated is true in this case.

Comment: @orlp Thanks for this, rather unsubstantiated, opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(n)$ be the probability of a tree with depth n having a white path from the root to a leaf. Starting from the root and working down, notice that there are 3 possibilities for the first level:

1. Both edges are white (probability $.25$), reducing our problem to two independent cases of trees with depth $n-1$
2. Both edges are black (probability $.25$), in which case we've already lost
3. One edge is black, one edge is white (probability $.5$), in which case we simply have a tree with depth $n-1$

Combining these three mutually exclusive cases by the law of total probability yields:
\begin{align*}
p(n) &= .25(1 - (1 - p(n-1))^2) + .5p(n-1) \\
     &= -\frac{1}{4}p(n-1)^2 + p(n-1)
\end{align*}

Can you solve that recurrence and get a closed form? Not to inherently imply the existence of a closed form. I'm simply stating that *if you can* find such a closed form, that would allow you to finish the problem.

Comment: "Can you solve that recurrence and get a closed form?" I cannot. Can you? (You may want to read my comment to @orlp's answer for some context, which makes that I find your question rather odd.)

Comment: Oh that wasn't a rhetorical question -- I didn't know how to solve that recurrence and was hoping the OP could. I posted this answer when @orlp had only posted the hint and OP had expressed that he didn't know how to use the hint.

Comment: The you turned to the most misleading formulation one can imagine, sorry to say.

Comment: Quite frankly, I don't see how asking an honest question in my best effort to help OP is "turning to the most misleading formulation one can imagine". What I arrived at is a necessary stepping stone in the problem, even if actually solving the recurrence is not. If you want me to say that your approach was better than mine, I'm happy to. You solved this problem fully and I didn't. You did better than me. I just think it's unfair of you to imply I had some sort of intention of misleading OP.

Comment: Once again, whether you wanted it or not, the formulation ending your post is most misleading. Now you know, and you can choose to avoid repeating this mistake, or not.

Comment: Here, allow me to edit my post so it is no longer misleading.